# fortran in Xcode

Tags: xcode, fortran

how I can programming in fortran with XCode 3.2 for OSX?

I try with this plugin for gfortran
http://www.macresearch.org/xcode_gfortran_plugin_update
but don't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not using Xcode. Because Xcode was not designed for Fortran, there are no significant advantages in using it as an IDE. I'd suggest using Textmate.

Answer (score 0):

I use [gfortran](http://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/) for compiling. You can find other compilers out there too, like [g95](http://www.g95.org/index.shtml). For text editing Fortran, I use [Smultron](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smultron/), or "vi" in the command line mode. CHEERS